# PyTest: ValueError: did not yield a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I just created a pytest fixture and i can't use yield, since it gives me an error
I tried different stuff without success.

What i'm doing wrong?

```
@pytest.fixture
def names_resp():
    with open('ropo_resp.json', 'r') as names:
        global data
        data = json.load(names)
        return data
    
    yield
    print("a")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you even trying to test.

Comment: the function in effect greats a generator,  when used in a place where multiple values are processed (example a for loop)  each yeald returns the next value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fixture` is expecting to `yield` something, even if it's `None`. But your `yield` is unreachable since you have `return` before it

```
@pytest.fixture
def names_resp():
    with open('ropo_resp.json', 'r') as names:
        data = json.load(names)
    yield data
    print("a")
```

Comment: Moved the return and it works perfectly. Thanks!